# The border of a table td won't extend to a picture

Tags: html, image, size, border, pixel

The border of a table td won't extend to a picture. Pictures will be uploaded. (I use VS Code but it also didn't work in other environments)

```css
body    {
    background-color:lightblue;

    background-image: url("Cherry_Wood_bg.jpg");
        }

h1      {
    font-family:Courier;

    font-size:50px;
   
    color:pink; 
   
        }

td, th  {

    border: 10px solid goldenrod;  
    border="10"

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Combinations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>
    Which Combination do you use?
</h1>    

<table>


<td>
    <img src="Option1_1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<td>
    <img src="Option2_1.jpg" width="140%" height="60%">
</td>
<td> This is a Test and this will show that it should adjust so yeah </td>
<tr>
</tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr>
</tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_4.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_5.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_6.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_8.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_9.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_10.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_11.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_12.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_13.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_14.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_15.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_16.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_17.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_18.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_19.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_20.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_21.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_22.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_23.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>
<tr></tr>
<td>
    <img src="Option1_24.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</td>





</table>

<!--tr nach rechts, td nach unten-->
</body>
</html>
```

I looked it up on and tried things like deleting borders of the border (left, right etc.), I tried making the picture smaller and bigger, adjusting its size, and just tried about everything I saw online.

Comment: `border="10"` is css invalid syntax.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do you have any other Ideas?
It also doesn't work with more pictures added but the border does adjust to the text. 

https://photos.app.goo.gl/1hu296UDjPfgGELs8

@MisterJojo